# Kurento 6.5 : kurento media server is not running

Tags: kurento

I have installed latest stable version of KMS 6.5 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) machine but unfortunately kurento media server is not able to run. It is getting stuck at loading modules configuration.

**KMS Version:**

```
Version: 6.5.0
Found modules:
    Module: 'core' version '6.5.1~20.gbbd29c0'
    Module: 'elements' version '6.5.0'
    Module: 'filters' version '6.5.0'
```

**Logs:**

```
2016-06-07 13:32:57,802641 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]   debug KurentoMediaServer        main.cpp:194 main()  Dumping logs to /var/log/kurento-media-server
2016-06-07 13:32:57,802899 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:156 loadModules()  Looking for modules in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules
2016-06-07 13:32:57,803569 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]   debug KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:89 loadModule()  Module loaded from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmsfiltersmodule.so
2016-06-07 13:32:57,803615 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:135 loadModule()  Loaded filters version 6.5.0 generated at May 30 2016 15:55:46
2016-06-07 13:32:57,806695 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]   debug KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:89 loadModule()  Module loaded from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmselementsmodule.so
2016-06-07 13:32:57,806765 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:135 loadModule()  Loaded elements version 6.5.0 generated at May 30 2016 15:46:36
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807081 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]   debug KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:89 loadModule()  Module loaded from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmscoremodule.so
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807119 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:135 loadModule()  Loaded core version 6.5.1~20.gbbd29c0 generated at Jun  3 2016 15:31:39
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807164 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoMediaServer        main.cpp:238 main()  Kmsc version: 6.5.0
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807187 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoMediaServer        main.cpp:239 main()  Compiled at: May 30 2016 17:27:03
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807209 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoLoadConfig         loadConfig.cpp:229 loadConfig()  Reading configuration from: /etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807363 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoLoadConfig         loadConfig.cpp:166 loadModulesConfigFromDir()  Looking for config files in /etc/kurento/modules
2016-06-07 13:32:57,807411 4667 [0x00007f7cfba9c8c0]    info KurentoLoadConfig         loadConfig.cpp:166 loadModulesConfigFromDir()  Looking for config files in /etc/kurento/modules/kurento
```

**Media Server Error Logs:**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error> >'
  what():  /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/SdpEndpoint.conf.json(23): expected value
[31;1mAborted[0m (thread [33;1m140174774880448[0m, pid [33;1m4667[0m)
Stack trace:
[34;1m[__GI_raise][0m
nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c[32;1m:56[0m
[34;1m[__GI_abort][0m
/build/eglibc-3GlaMS/eglibc-2.19/stdlib/abort.c[32;1m:91[0m
[34;1m[__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()][0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6[32;1m:0x60535[0m
[34;1m[std::rethrow_exception(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr)][0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6[32;1m:0x5E6D6[0m
[34;1m[std::terminate()][0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6[32;1m:0x5E703[0m
[34;1m[__cxa_throw][0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6[32;1m:0x5E922[0m
[34;1m[void boost::throw_exception<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error> >(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error> const&)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x5038C9[0m
[34;1m[void boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error>(boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error const&, char const*, char const*, int)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x50399D[0m
[34;1m[void boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json_internal<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >(std::basic_istream<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::key_type::value_type, std::char_traits<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::key_type::value_type> >&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, std::string const&)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x516954[0m
[34;1m[void boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >(std::string const&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, std::locale const&)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x516C07[0m
[34;1m[kurento::mergePropertyTrees(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > const&, int)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x4FEAF5[0m
[34;1m[kurento::mergePropertyTrees(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > const&, int)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x4FF073[0m
[34;1m[kurento::mergePropertyTrees(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > const&, int)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x4FF598[0m
[34;1m[kurento::loadConfig(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >&, std::string const&, std::string const&)][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x4FFD94[0m
[34;1m[main][0m
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server[32;1m:0x4D476C[0m
[34;1m[__libc_start_main][0m
/build/eglibc-3GlaMS/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c[32;1m:321[0m
```

---

**EDIT 1**

As per @santoscadenas, here are the contents of `SdpEndpoint.conf.json`

```
{
  "numAudioMedias" : 1,
  "numVideoMedias" : 1,
  "audioCodecs" : [
    {
      "name" : "opus/48000/2"
// Next is an example about how a codec can be configured.
// WARNING: Usage of properties is not yet supported
//      "properties" : {
//        "maxcodedaudiobandwidth" : "16000",
//        "maxaveragebitrate" : "20000",
//        "stereo": "1",
//        "useinbandfec" : "1",
//        "usedtx" : "0"
//      }
//    },
    {
      "name" : "PCMU/8000"
    },
   {
    "name" : "AMR/8000"
    }
  ],
  "videoCodecs" : [
    {
      "name" : "VP8/90000"
    },
    {
      "name" : "H264/90000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your configuration file `SdpEndpoint.conf.json` has some issues, check if it is correctly formed.

Change your current configuration by this one:

```
{
  "numAudioMedias" : 1,
  "numVideoMedias" : 1,
  "audioCodecs" : [
    {
      "name" : "opus/48000/2"
// Next is an example about how a codec can be configured.
// WARNING: Usage of properties is not yet supported
//      "properties" : {
//        "maxcodedaudiobandwidth" : "16000",
//        "maxaveragebitrate" : "20000",
//        "stereo": "1",
//        "useinbandfec" : "1",
//        "usedtx" : "0"
//      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "PCMU/8000"
    },
    {
      "name" : "AMR/8000"
    }
  ],
  "videoCodecs" : [
    {
      "name" : "VP8/90000"
    },
    {
      "name" : "H264/90000"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there is an extra comment on the opus entry.

Comment: ok, but 'SdpEndpoint.conf.json' file has the same contents as of file on kms 6.4 installed on my another machine.

Comment: Can you paste the file contents? Because the code that parses is the same than in previous versions. Most probably is something in the file.